# Switching tabs from different App in my SalesForce account forces login

Tags: salesforce1-app, force.com, administration

I have several apps installed in my SalesForce account, for some reason 
when I try to switch from one tab to another tab (which belongs to a different app) I get a log-in screen.

Did you encounter this?

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the following security option:

"Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used"

under Session Settings

It now works fine